# コンテンツの中に見出しを表示させたい

Tags: html

xhtml·css初心者です。皆様の知恵をお貸しください。
以下のように表示させたいですが、どう書けばよろしいでしょうか

試したことはtd中にthを入れましたが、無効で言われて無視されました。

th見出し1/th
    td文言1
       th見出し2/th
         td文言2/td
       th見出し3/th
          td文言3/td
    /td
図を描くのが下手すぎて申し訳ありません
なんとかイメージしていただければと思います。

ほかに何か不明点あれば補足させていただきます。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 恐らくうまく表示されないため`<>`を省略されているのかと思いますが、質問の本文にHTMLを貼り付けたあと、HTMLの部分のみ選択した状態で`{}`をクリックすればきれいに表示されるはずなので、問題の出ているHTMLを正しく貼り直してみてください。 / 質問は後からでも [編集] できます。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12211547662

Answer (score 0):

恐らく以下の様なHTMLになるかと思います。

- 行を定義するために`<tr>～</tr>`が必要です。この中に`<th>`や`<td>`を含めます。
- セルを結合するには`<th>`や`<td>`に`colspan=""`、`rowspan=""`を追加します。

```html
<html>
<body>
<table border=1>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="3">見出し1</td>
  <td colspan="2">文言1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>見出し2</th>
  <th>見出し3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>文言2</td>
  <td>文言3</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

参考:
[表を作る - TAG index](https://www.tagindex.com/html_tag/table/table.html)
[セルを結合する - TAG index](https://www.tagindex.com/html_tag/table/td_span.html)